# Tem como quantificar os valores que atendem uma condição de um loop?

Tags: c#, c, while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int contador = 1;

while (contador <= 322) {

    if (contador % 3 == 0) {

        printf("%i\n", contador);

    }//if

    contador++;

}//while

printf("\nNo intervalo de 1 a 322.\n\n");
printf("Estes sao os multiplos de 3.\n");

return 0;
}//main
```

No caso como eu faria para quantificar os valores validos para condição múltiplos de 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso, você precisa contabilizar as vezes que isso acontece. usei a variável totalDeMutiplos para essa função. cada vez que a condição do if for verdadeira, incrementa a variável

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int contador = 1;
int totalDeMutiplos=0;

while (contador <= 322) {

    if (contador % 3 == 0) {

        printf("%i\n", contador);
        totalDeMutiplos++;

    }//if

    contador++;

}//while

printf("\nNo intervalo de 1 a 322.\n\n");
printf("Estes sao os multiplos de 3.\n");
printf("Foram cotabilizado um total de %d de multiplos de 3\n",totalDeMutiplos);
return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!